# Create a workflow rule when Lead status is changed from X to Y

Tags: workflow, leads

I want to create a workflow rule which should be triggered when I change the Lead Status value from 'Open: Not Contacted' to 'Open: Working'

Any help with this please?

Comment: do u care if the prev value was "Open: Not Contacted" ?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE - you'll find the community is most helpful when you demonstrate that you tried something yourself first and found it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

In the workflow rule you will want to set it to "created, and every time it's edited" in order to be able to use `ISCHANGED()` and `PRIORVALUE()` functions. Then you will be able to check if the Status was changed and if the `PRIORVALUE()` meets your criteria and if the current value meets your criteria.
This help article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004046&language=en_US) is a little different from what you are trying to do but gives an example of how to use `PRIORVALUE()` with a picklist field.

> **Description**
>
> If you need to add a field to the Opportunity Object to show the Stage
>   an Opportunity had before it was changed to the current Stage you can
>   do so by doing the following:
>
> Note: you can use an Opportunity History report but this field allows
>   you to just see the last Stage the Opportunity was in.
>
> Once the Previous Stage is included on the Opportunity Object it can
>   be used in Opportunity Reports.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> For this workaround you will need to:
>
> 1) Create a new text field on the Opportunity Object called Previous
>   Stage. (It can be hidden if needed)
>
> 2) Create a workflow rule that triggers a field update the Previous
>   Stage field..
>
> 3) Add a Field update action with the formula specified below.
>
> 1. Login and go to: Your Name | Setup | App Setup | Customise | Opportunities | Fields Create a new Text field called "Previous
>      Stage".
> 2. Go to: Your Name | Setup | App Setup | Create | Workflow & Approvals | Workflow Rules Click on New Rule and create a Workflow on
>      Opportunities called "Previous Value".
>
> Select "created, and every time it's edited" and enter the Formula
>   Criteria:

```
ISCHANGED(StageName)
```

> 3. Save the Workflow Rule and add a field update called "Previous Stage Update". Select to update the "Previous Stage" field you created
>      in Step 1 above. When prompted after selecting the field select "Use a
>      formula to set the new value" Click on Show Formula Editor.
>
> Paste in the following Formula:

```
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),"Stage1"),"Stage1",
    IF(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),"Stage2"),"Stage2",
    IF(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),"Stage3"),"Stage3",
    IF(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),"Stage4"),"Stage4",
    ""))))
```

> You will need to adjust the Formula above to include all of the Active
>   Stages. Replace Stage1 with the first Stage listed and so on.
>
> Add an additional ")" to the end of the Formula for each Stage added.
>
> Then Save the Workflow Field Update.
>
> Finally test the new field and check it is working by editing an
>   Opportunity and changing the Stage.