# Pick list value from open to pending on lead object

Tags: workflow

On lead object we have status picklist field. If picklist value is changed from New to open then Date field should get update on custom object(Value__c) . I am writing work flow. Please help me with function logic.

Comment: What is relationship between Lead and custom object? date field should be updated to what? please elaborate..

Comment: We have lookup relation for lead and custom object.If lead status is changed from New to Pending then Date__c should get updated by today's date.

Comment: related question -> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/59806/create-a-workflow-rule-when-lead-status-is-changed-from-x-to-y?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Choose Immediate Action use formula as ***TODAY()*** (or) **NOW()** to capture Time

[image]